# Groovy character data type

Tags: groovy, character

I have a question regarding groovy and hope I can get some help. This code sample bellow is a groovy merge function and I want to write a new merge function but for different data type. However, I want to understand first the reason of including String ABC = value.get(0).toString();

From my understanding, this is only to convert the data type from whatever type to string, but in case I do not need to convert anything and just want to keep the same data type, for example character data type. I thought of char.get(0).char(); but this just doesn't make sense to me. Another thing is, if I just want to ignore it and do just my conditional statement then how would my groovy know the data type assigned to it?

```
public class myClass
{

    Object merge(List<Object>values) 
    {

        String ABC = values.get(0).toString(); 


            if(ABC== 'p') 
        {

            return 1;

        }

        else if(ABC == 'N') 
        {

            return -1 ;
        }


    }
```

Comment: just remove `.toString()` ? ang you can get datatype with `.getClass()`

Comment: You cast in groovy either with `as`.  E.g. `char abc = values[0] as char` or like in java (prefix in parens).  E.g. `char abc = (char)values[0]`.  Yet it strikes me odd, that you use Object all over the place while you are going for array of chars to int. Just use the proper declaration and you dont have to cast and if groovy can not cast for the caller, the caller gets a proper error.